# Can't resize a partition using Mini Tool?

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad that came with Windows. Awhile ago, I installed Ubuntu to dual boot both OS. I now want to resize the Ubuntu partition as I am running out of storage.

When I open Mini Tool Partition Wizard, I do not have the option to resize the partition. I am doing this from the booted Windows OS to resize the Ubuntu partition.

Not too familiar with this stuff, any suggestions.